# Webcam access with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, video, getusermedia

i used this Code Example:

```
<video autoplay playsinline style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></video>
<script>
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: 'user' } })
        .then(stream => document.querySelector('video').srcObject = stream);
</script>
```

I want to get access through my webcam with a WebApp using Angular. I changed the Code to Typescript like:

```
@ViewChild('myVideo') myVideo: any;

public takePicture(event?: any): void {
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: 'user' } })
.then(stream => this.myVideo.srcObject = stream);
}
```

in the .ts and

```
        <button (click)="takePicture($event)"></button>
        <video #myVideo autoplay playsinline style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></video>
```

in the html. Anyways the example code works in a normal file opened with a browser. But i can not translate the code for Angular. I dont get any Error message. The Browser is asking me for cam-permission but i dont see the input of my webcam.

Greetings from Germany!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you're not getting any output is that while using viewchild you have to access the srcObject via

```
this.myVideo.nativeElement.srcObject
```

you can follow the above way or use good old javascript document.getElement like

```
public takePicture(event?: any): void {
const vid = document.getElementById("videoelementId")
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: 'user' } })
.then(stream => vid.srcObject = stream);
}
```

I have developed a plugin based on this ,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-my-photo

https://github.com/Faiz-exe/get-my-photo

Comment: Thank you very much :). It worked with the line above
  "this.myVideo.nativeElement.srcObject" instead of "this.myVideo.srcObject".
I can not do getElement with Angular unfortunaly. I need to get my element by "@viewChild". 
Anyway thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 1):

```
  //selfie
  WIDTH = 1136;
  HEIGHT = 840;
  @ViewChild("video") video: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("canvas") canvas: ElementRef;
  isCaptured: boolean;
  error: any;



  setupDevices() {

    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {

      console.log('ghiles')
      console.log(navigator.mediaDevices)
      console.log('ghiles')

      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })

        .then(stream => {
          this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
          this.video.nativeElement.play();
          console.log(stream)
        })
        .catch( err => {
          console.log(err)
          // alert('Autorisation camera refusée');
          console.log('Autorisation camera refusée');

          const dialogReference: MatDialogRef<any, any> = this.MatDialog.open(AutorisationComponent, {
            width: '1728px'
        });
  


        })

 
    }
  }


  capture() {


    this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").drawImage(this.video.nativeElement, 0, 0, this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);
    console.log(this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d"))
    this.isCaptured = true;
    var dataurl = this.canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL();
    this.selfieImg = {
      filename: 'selfie',
      is_link: false,
      mimetype: 'image/png',
      source: dataurl.split(',')[1]
    }

    console.log(this.selfieImg)

  }
```